# How to Make the first index column as null?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to rename the "key" to null from the last DF result?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df.pivot(index='Metric', columns='key', values='value').reset_index()\
  .rename_axis(columns=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
df1 = df.rename(columns = {"" : "Metric", "seg1", ""seg2})
```

Of course, you change "df1" to fit your final result.